# Linq except return whole table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table of items using linq to entities, say:

```
ID | Name | Attb1 | Attb2
1 | Apple | Green | Juicy
2 | Orange | Orange | sweet
```

etc

I have another list with just ID's in it.

Using Linq I want to return all fields from the item table except where the ID is in the list. i.e. if my list just has '1' in it I want to return `2 | orange | orange | sweet`

Comment: What is your table?  Linq to entitles?  A DataTable? a Class with these properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
var result = table.Where(x => !list.Contains(x.id));
```

where I have assumed that `table` holds all the rows of your table and `list` contains the ids that you want to exclude.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was trying to do some sort of .Except